# Do grad schools need an official transcript from universities where I was an exchange student for only one semester?

Tags: graduate-admissions, student-exchange, transcript-of-records

I am a European non-EU student that went on an Erasmus exchange for one semester in the UK during my third year. Now, two and a half years later, I am applying to grad schools in the US, and the official transcript in my home university lists the courses taken in my exchange.

However, I was wondering if I need an official transcript from the Erasmus university as well. Getting this would be a big problem, since they only give them in person, and I have no way of getting one. Is it enough that the courses I took on my exchange are listed on my home university transcript, or will I have to do the impossible and get one from the Erasmus university too?

Comment: I just don't want to be disqualified by a technicality.

Comment: Are the grades of those courses you took in Erasmus university also recorded on the official transcript of your home university?

Comment: The courses taken in the exchange were in a pass/fail basis, and the results are listed in the official transcript.

Comment: Then I believe the **official** transcript of your home university is good enough. The pass/fail results are already officially recorded.

Comment: On the other hand, I think that you should privide both transcripts of your current university and from the UK university that you spend that semester.

Comment: The problem with getting the UK transcript is that I will only be able to pick the transcript up in person. I can't do that, since I live far away, need a visa to go to the UK, and can't afford to spend all that money.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that, the fact that your official transcript lists the courses indicates that some authority has vetted the courses and consider that credit-worthy.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the UK university won't send the transcript by mail, even after you've told them how difficult it would be for you to collect it in person? That's a ridiculous restriction.

Comment: I had to get an official transcript from a community college I took a single extracurricular class at during high school to satisfy my (American) graduate school.  FWIW, I think this is typical here.¶  I've never even _heard_ of a university not being willing to send electronic, let alone _mailed_ official transcripts.  If you do end up having to go there in person, do their records department a favor and introduce them to stone tools.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely to be specific to a particular graduate school, but I studied in the UK for a year during my US undergraduate education. The courses and grades were listed on my transcript. The graduate school that I applied to (and to which I was accepted) did not require a separate transcript from the UK university.